# Error while calling Javascript from XSL file

Tags: javascript, xslt

Am trying to call javascript from within my XSL file, but it is not working..

Wanted to know: 
1. Is there any problem with my XSL file... (see below)
2. **Is there any system configuration to be done before running XSL with Javascript?**

IE 9.0 is being used for testing of this prototype XSL.

Here is the content of XSL file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"  
xmlns:result="http://www.example.com/results"  
extension-element-prefixes="result" >  

   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>  


   <lxslt:component prefix="result" functions="myParse">  
    <lxslt:script lang="javascript">  
        function myParse()   
        {  
            return "just testing....";  
        }  
    </lxslt:script>  
  </lxslt:component>  

    <xsl:template match="/">        

        <xsl:for-each select="comment/MyObject">  

            <xsl:variable name="temp" select="@objectInformation" />  

             <xsl:variable name="temp2">  
                <xsl:value-of>  
                    <script type="text/javascript">  
                        result:myParse()  
                    </script>      
                </xsl:value-of>                  
            </xsl:variable>  

            <xsl:value-of select="string($temp2)"/>  

        </xsl:for-each>  

    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tried with below LOCs as well.. but no luck.                                                               <lxslt:script lang="javascript">
     result:myParse()
</lxslt:script>

Comment: The syntax you're trying to use to add the script is the xalan syntax, but IE does not support xalan. IE supports msxsl, which also has a way of including JavaScript, but other browsers do not. Where do you plan to ultimately use this XSLT?

Comment: @JLRishe This XSL is prototype. The main XSL file will be used to generate PDF out of an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax for calling your function in this case would be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="result:myParse()" />
```

Or you could just do this in this case:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp2" select="result:myParse()" />
```

And are you sure that the namespace in this case shouldn't be http://xml.apache.org/xalan?

Comment: Tried both and also tried using namespace xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" but yet... still unresolved.